# How to fix item on left side of Appbar, while keep title in center of Appbar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to put "Logo2" Widget on the left side, while the "Title logo" is in the center. I was trying with Expanded inside Row, and with Stack but I can't get it on the spot. I also need it to work on different screen sizes.

[image: Image(I can't insert it, cause of rep)]

Current code:

```
appBar: AppBar(
  leading: Icon(Icons.menu),
  centerTitle: true,
  title: Container(child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(flex:2, child: Text("Logo 2")),
      Expanded(flex:4, child: Text("Title logo")),
    ],
  )),
  actions: <Widget>[
    IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.person_pin),
      onPressed: (){},
    )
  ],
),
```

Comment: I think that row will work if `centerTile` is false.

Comment: Doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrapping `Row` with `Container`, you can directly pass the `Row` widget and set `flex` property of `Logo 2` to 1 instead of 2. `AppBar` widget also contains a property named `titleSpacing` which if set to 0, helps to keep the title `centered`. Working code below:

```
appBar: AppBar(
          titleSpacing: 0,
          leading: Icon(Icons.menu),
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Text('Logo 2'),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Text('Title Logo')
              )
            ],
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person_pin),
              onPressed: (){},
            )
          ],
        ),
```

[image]

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: I tried but "Title logo" is not centered, I believe it's because action Widget changes center title property.